# How to retrieve data from Firefox sync account?

Tags: firefox, sync

I've got a sudden upgrade at work. I thought of synchronizing my bookmarks between old and new machines, and created a Sync account on an old one. But while I was busy playing with the new hardware, my old machine was gone, so I can't actually synchronize with it now.

However, I still have the key to my Sync account and I thought maybe it is still possible to retrieve my data as for the last day my old machine was online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the old computer completed a sync, you should be able to setup the new computer to sync the data that's stored in the cloud. [Instructions here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-do-i-manage-my-firefox-sync-account)

**How do I access my Sync account from any computer?**

```
Open a browser.
Go to https://account.services.mozilla.com.
Enter your username and password.
Click Login. Your Firefox Sync account management portal will load.
```